# Proof that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a group

Tags: group-theory

We got this question for homework and I have no idea how to go about it: 
Show that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an additive group for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do this question?

Comment: Just show that modular addition is closed, has an identity element, has an additive inverse, and is associative.

Comment: If you know what a group is, you know what axioms a set with an operation has to satisfy to qualify as a group. In that case you should *check to see if this set with an operation satisfies those axioms.*

Comment: You could "warm up" by solving a *less general* version of the same problem.  IOW, instead of proving the assertion for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, you could prove it for some specific (but easy) values of $n$.  I suggest that you try the cases where $n \in \{0, 1, -1, 2\}$.  (Start by making sure you understand what the quotients $\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/1\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/(-1)\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ *are*!  Hint: these are all fancy names for things you have known since elementary school.)

Comment: You don't say whether you know what the notation $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ means. Often when people say "I have no idea how to do this exercise" what they really mean is "I have no idea what this exercise even means".  If that's what is happening to you, then your first job is to look in the book or in your class notes to find out what it means for something to be an additive group, and what $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ means.  Then you can start to look into whether $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is an additive group.

Comment: What definition of $\,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\,$ are you working with? If you've studied quotient groups then this is immediate. If not, then what does $\,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\,$ denote?

Answer (score 3):

Simply verify the group axioms.

1. Show the group is closed under the binary operation. I.e that a + b for all a,b is also in the group.
2. Show addition is associative. That is a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c
3. There exists an identity. (What could that be?)
4. There exists an inverse (-a) for every element a in the group.

If a set with a binary operation (+) satisfies these axioms it is a group.

Comment: I understand how to do this when were given a number such as n = 5 but we were told we have to use a general arguement and not just examples which I don't know how to apply when there is an infinite number of variables in the group.

Comment: I don't know precisely what you mean by variables when you say that there might be infinitely many of them but for any $n$ the corresponding group will be finite. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$  after all (effectively at least), so we have nothing to worry about.

The character of the proof will be the same regardless of the actual value of $n$, you can basically use a proof for the case of $5$ and rewrite it with $n$ replacing 5 (unless you did a brute force proof).

If $n$ wasn't an integer this would be a different story but thankfully it is.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $\mathbb Z$ is an abelian group (I assume you even know that already).
Show that $n\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. Show that for any abelaian group $A$ and subgroup $B$, $A/B$ is a group.